# Bootstrap CSS Align Text Middle Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap row with three columns. In the middle column, there is a input field which is increasing the height of the row and throwing aligning my text in the first div to be at the top.

[image]

[image]

I tried adding some css to align that div text in the middle but it wasn't working.

```
.filterOption{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

My html is very basic and looks like so:

```
if(field.isInput == '1'){
  output += '<div class="row">' +
  '<div class="col-md-2 filterOption">'+field.fieldName+'</div>' +
  '<div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_'+field.fieldID+'" name="field_'+field.fieldID+'" placeholder="'+field.placeholder+'"></div>' +
  '<div class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></div>' +
  '</div>';
}
```

**The Question**

How can I go about getting the label / content in the first div to be aligned in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

You may use translateY:

```css
.filterOption{
  position:relative;
  transform: translateY(30%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 filterOption">'+field.fieldName+'</div>
    <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_'+field.fieldID+'"
                                 name="field_'+field.fieldID+'" placeholder="'+field.placeholder+'"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add top and bottom padding to this cell.

```
.filterOption{
   padding-top: 5px; //put correct pixel
   padding-bottom: 5px; //put correct pixel
}
```